# Averaging Ripley's K or L function for several samples

Tags: confidence-interval, spatial, mean, point-process, ripley-k

Would much appreciate to hear your opinion about the following strategy:

I have several samples of point patterns, witch are results from somw replicated experiment. The number of points and area of observation vary from experiment to experiment. I would like to test a null hypothesis on CSR for this set of data using Ripley's function and make a conclusion for the overall population.

For each experiment I compute L function and corresponding confidence envelopes. In the end I average all the L functions and CEs and look at the behavior of the this averaged quantities.

Do you think that averaging can lead to misleading results?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest that you look at chapter 16 of Baddeley, Rubak & Turner (2015) *Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R*. Specifically Section 16.8 *Analysing summary functions from replicated patterns* seems very relevant to what you describe here. In that section you will learn about the generic function `pool` (with methods `pool.fv` and `pool.envelope`) that you can use to pool the estimates correctly. If you don't have access to the book you can have a look at the relevant vignette:

```
vignette("replicated", package="spatstat")
```

Please be aware that the envelopes we provide by default in `spatstat` are NOT confidence envelopes! These are simulation envelopes under a given null model and indicate (by default) the pointwise non-rejection region of a Monte Carlo test. Again this is explained in detail in the book in chapter 10, but you can also find a short discussion explaining the difference in Section 7.3.3 *Use of the empirical K-function* which has the advantage of being part of the free sample chapter 7 downloadable from the companion website http://book.spatstat.org

**Disclaimer:** I'm coauthor of the book mentioned above, but this is not (only) from shameless self promotion -- it is also the definitive reference on `spatstat`, so it is very relevant if you use `spatstat` to do your actual calculations.

Comment: I successfully applied pooling. I plan to use MAD test on the pooled data. For example `E1<-envelope(Data1,Lest, savefuns=TRUE)  E2<-envelope(Data1,Lest, savefuns=TRUE); p<-pool(E1,E2); mad.test(p)`. To me it seems to be a fair strategy to make a conclusion about population Data1, Data2.  I was wandering if I am missing something?Thanks again!

Comment: Im trying to achieve something similar, I have a bunch of 3d tiff images each have a bunch of pixelized cells and would like to see if they are clustered or not but then I would like to compare the result with other tiff images. The main issue is that different tiff images have different windows.

Comment: @Ali_Nass it is unclear to me how you would apply Ripley's K-function to "a bunch of 3d tiff images". I think your situation is different enough to warrant a new question where you: Clearly describe which question you are trying to answer, describe what you have done so far and show your data (or synthetic data that has the same structure) in a reproducible example. I don't think anyone can help you based on this comment.

Comment: @EgeRubak I asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76979448/calculate-clustering-for-3d-cells-in-a-pixel-tif-image but didn't get any comments/answers. 
Basically what im trying to do, this is a 3d representation of one of my tiff images https://imgur.com/a/vAVuebM , I built a convex hull around it. I want to check if the cell distribution is clustered or not within this convex. But then I have many more tiff images with different convex hull, so I would like to average them out. Not sure if this makes more sense